# Ubuntu slowed down after unplugging charging cable

Tags: laptop, battery

When I accidentally unplug the charging cable and connect again, Ubuntu begins to slow down.

This continues even after reboot and in any desktop environment (XFCE, Cinamon, Gnome, etc). And then returns to normal operation, for reasons unknown to me.

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean exactly with "Ubuntu begings to slow down". Also please add a proper title instead of using the first sentence of your question as a title.

Comment: PCs will usually go into a lower power mode when not plugged in. Fans will slow down, cpu will throttle a bit more, etc. Depending on bios settings, firmware, and os settings. Do you have a benchmark or something more specific in how it is becoming slower? Do webpages load slower, do applications launch slower, how much slower?

Comment: I saw this too, much too often on Ubuntu 14.04. Unplugging the cable occasionally permanently shifts down the CPU frequency, until rebooting.  Modifying the contents of `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` does not make any difference (normally it does, but after this slowdown happens, this setting is just ignored).